# HP printer ( LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw)

Tags: hp, laserjet

I have this information of my system:

OS:  Netrunner 14

System:  Linux 3.13.0-44-generic i686

KDE:  4.13.3

---

I bought yesterday printer from HP ( LaserJet Pro MFP M125nw)

I know from the beginning this HP type is already configured  with my system , No need to install the package of HP .

So, when I plug the USP cable to my PC It gives me a massage that the printer has been configured . but When I try to print any pages or test paper ...It's not printing at all ..

So could any one help me to solve this problem 
thanks a lot 
oudai ,,

Answer (score 4):

I have the same printer and Ubuntu 14.04, and I was also wondering why the test page won't get printed, even though the set-up seemed to be successful.

After a while I recognized that the system couldn't auto-install a proprietary plug-in for the driver, but it is fairly easy to install with the pre-installed tool hplip. Just type the command `hp-setup` and follow the instructions.

It should be quite straight forward, but you can find more information here:
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/support.html

Comment: Same as m125a, run `hp-setup` to install and it works well.